# Doxygen RTF format equivalent to default Doxygen HTML output

Tags: html, doxygen, rtf

Previously, I have used Doxygen to make html output for my code.  Right out of the box, Doxygen makes pretty good html documentation.  With a little stylesheet modification, I can make it look great.

For my current project, I need to release documentation in a Word doc.  I enabled Doxygen's RTF output to find that it looks terrible.  Since I can create my own RTF document and manually make lists/tables/etc that look just like Doxygen's html output, it seems like Doxygen should be capable of making RTF output that's equivalent to their html output.

Creating doxygen's RTF stylesheet file gives me a template in a syntax that's a whole lot less documented than html stylesheets.  Reading through the options, it doesn't seem like they have all of the settings that are available in the html stylesheet either.

Is it possible to modify the RTF stylesheet so that it gives me output that's equivalent to the default html output from Doxygen?  If so, has anyone already done this who'd like to send me a link to it?  Honestly, I'd be happy just to get a link to a guide that tells me the syntax for the RTF stylesheet.